How can I set arbitrary stylesheet parameters from XML source document?
I have a collection of DocBook XML (article) documents and the following requirement: most documents should be rendered (to PDF) without numbered sections, but some documents do require numbered sections. I want to signal the numbered section requirement in the document, not, say, keep an external manifest of which document needs which treatment.
My first thought was: processing instruction that sets the (DocBook XSL) section.autolabel parameter. My second thought was: why stop there? What would be good is a processing instruction that would set an arbitrary parameter to an arbitrary value, just like what is described here: PI Parameters. It seems that the xslt-param PI there is only supported by some ancient version of Firefox. We're using Saxon HE 12.
Next up, I can get most of the way there in XSLT (using the DocBook pi-attribute template):
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('xslt-param')">
  <xsl:variable name="name">
    <xsl:call-template name="pi-attribute">
      <xsl:with-param name="pis" select="."/>
      <xsl:with-param name="attribute" select="'name'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="value">
    <xsl:call-template name="pi-attribute">
      <xsl:with-param name="pis" select="."/>
      <xsl:with-param name="attribute" select="'value'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:param name="$name" select="$value"/>
</xsl:template>

But at that point, I can't reference $name as the name for the parameter: the xsl:param line there is a syntax error.
Questions:

Can I get there in XSLT alone?
Have I missed something in the DocBook XSL stylesheets (1.79.2) (beyond using the dbfo mechanism to create a specific PI for section.autolabel)?
Do any XSLT processors offer extensions for doing this?


I thought the xslTNG stylesheets supported that, but apparently not (yet). I've added an issue: https://github.com/docbook/xslTNG/issues/506
I'm behind on updates to the stylesheets but hope to get back to them soon.

Thanks Norm. Am I right to conclude that this can't be done in a general way with XSLT alone? (That is, I can add a PI for section.autolabel in my 1.79.2 customisation layer, but something like  would be handy.)

There's no XSLT language feature for doing this. I've generally approached the problme with processing instructions tuned for each parameter db-this, db-that, db-the-other, but I guess a single xslt-param style processing instruction could be made to work.

Historically, I'd have worried about performance because each parameter would have to search the document for a possible override. (There are a few hundred parameters, say, and computers are fast, so perhaps that worry is unfounded. It's certainly unmeasured). But in modern XSLT, it might be practical to do it with one pre-processing step. Something to consider when I get back to the xslTNG stylesheets.

In principle (without knowing the DocBook stylesheets in detail), you can write a stylesheet module that imports the DocBook stylesheets, and provides an override for the declaration of the section.autolabel parameter; the override can be provided as either an xsl:param or xsl:variable declaration, and its select attribute can initialise the value of the parameter by selecting data from the source document of the transformation. You then need to initiate the transformation to execute the overriding stylesheet module rather than the original (overridden) DocBook module.

Thanks Michael, yes that's exactly what I've done for section.autolabel in particular. What I was wondering was whether there's a mechanism for overriding an arbitrary parameter in general, whose name isn't known ahead of time. Seems like the answer is no.

You could consider invoking the transformation from another stylesheet using fn:transform().
